# Why is `replace(dataclass, **kwargs)` a function, and not a member?

Tags: python, object-oriented-design, api-design

Imagine a simple data class:

```py
@dataclass
class Settings:
  m: int
  s: str

old = Settings(m=10, s="ten")
```

It feels normal to write `new = old.replace(m=1)`, but we have to write `new = replace(old, m=1)`.  It feels so normal that I see people adding a member `replace(self, **kwargs)` to their dataclass types.

I see a single possible reason for this design choice, which I think is a bit purist: it would prevent dataclass members to be called 'replace'.  Adding an underscore suffix would have solved that mostly  (like with `namedtuple`), so I was wondering if the 'pollution' argument was indeed the rationale for choosing the non-member function.

EDIT: I'm not interested in hypotheses or opinions; I'm in pursuit of the history of this decision (which I respect).

Comment: I think this is a better forum than where the question was posted originally: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70201906/6610

Comment: [Could you please delete the copy on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/228441)?

Comment: "It feels normal to write `x = lst.len()`, but we have to write `x = len(lst)`."

Comment: @Caleth Indeed.  What justifies the inconsistency?  Why is this choice not documented, is it so obvious, then?

Comment: I am explicitly not interested in opinions, but in the rationale that was _used_ for this decition.  I'll clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what it's worth, Raymond Hettinger (an author of `namedtuple`) has stated that he regrets opting for the `namedtuple._replace` approach (in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw), around the 20 minute mark) because it makes the method "seem private" when it's actually not. I can only assume that the `replace` function was created in order to avoid this issue, while simultaneously allowing unaware developers to implement a `dataclass.replace` attribute or method without risking overshadowing this functionality.